# IntelliJ IDEA "Tomcat manager" application

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, tomcat6, manager-app

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2 but I assume this question applies to previous versions as well.  In the Run/Debug Configurations dialog there is an option called "Deploy 'Tomcat Manager' application", but I haven't been able to find any documentation for how to use it in the IntelliJ help or online.  Has anyone had experience using this, and know what URL I could use to access it once Tomcat is running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL would be the same as for the vanilla Tomcat installation running outside of IDEA:

> http://host:port/manager/html

Please refer to the [Manager App HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) for additional information.